# How to remove leading zeros in a number using ampscript/javascript

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript

I want to remove leading zeros in a number. For example:

Input: `0001023`

Output:`1023`

Comment: could you please share your code, so we may know where you are stuck, and provide feedback? thanks

Comment: What's your context ?  Are you wanting to strip the leading zeros in an email or landing page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your input is a text field you can achieve this by using FormatNumber AMPscript function.

Here is an example:

```
%%=FormatNumber('0001023','G',en-US)=%%
```

Result: **1023**

Reference: [FormatNumber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatNumber.htm)

Comment: +1 If you know the number of leading zeros substring can also work

Answer (score 3):

If you requirement for small numbers you can use.

`parseInt('0001023')`

Comment: It'd be great if you could show how this might be used in a SSJS block.  I think it'll work, but not many people know what native JS functions work in SFMC SSJS environment.